# The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b) yet both, application and DLL are 32 bit

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, delphi-7, dllexport

Pretty much all the questions about this problem end up people trying to run 64 bit dll with 32 bit app, or 64 app - 32 dll. I have a diferent problem.

My delphi application is 32 bit, in visual studio i have set the target platform to x86. Using the unmanaged exports for DllExport funcionality.

Whenever i try to import the dll into my delphi application it shows me this error.

In a C# dll it looks like this

```
[DllExport("Open", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)] 
public static void Open() {
    MessageBox.Show("hello"); 
}
```

Inside delphi it looks like this

```
procedure Open(); cdecl; external 'mydll.dll';
```

When i run the app, it shows the error. Then i took another C# dll project made by another person, added a function just like the one i had in my own dll. Added the dll to the delphi app folder, ran the app and it was fine, i could call the `Open();`

I tried to see if there were any differences between my c# project and the other one and failed to see it. Everything looked similar.

Well, i started wondering what am i doing wrong. And i believe i have found the cause, sort of.

When i created a solution i picked `Windows Forms Application` (thinking that i need a form, which i will call from a dll later on), then went to properties and changed it to `Class library`, this was enough to compile it into a dll.

Then i figured i should try a different project type, i picked `Class library` project type this time. I quickly added same code as i had, compiled, moved dll to delphi app, and was surprised that it actually worked.

So my question is, WHY did it not work when i picked `Windows Form Application` and changed the type to dll? There was no difference in project files settings as far as i could see.

**EDIT 1:**

I have also figured a couple more things. The faulty solution (lets call it Solution A), as i said, was created by selecting `Windows Forms` (this creates a solution + project in one go).

Good solution (Solution B) was created by selecting `Class library`, again both the solution and project created all together.

If i delete the project from solution A, and add new project by selecting proper one (`Class library`) it will still compile a non working dll for me.

SO creating new solution (and selecting `Class library`) from scratch is a must for the dll to work.

Second thing i noticed were the difference in files that were generated once i compile the projects.
In a solution A i was getting a .dll, a .pdb and a `RGiesecke.DllExport.Metadata.dll`.
In a solution B i was getting a .dll, a .exp, a .lib and .pdb. No dllExport dll this time.
Both are DEBUG configurations.

Comment: Debug this with Dependency Viewer profile mode

Comment: If your OS is 64 bit, C# Dll in Any CPU platform is executed as 64 bit. In this case set x86 platform for C# Dll.

Comment: You can compare the resulting projects:
- working `Class library`
- borked `Windows Form Application` converted to Class library
With a file comparison tool and see different settings. Look specifically inside the .csproj files.